# Ideas for a better style for this table?

Tags: tables, booktabs

I have drawn the table showed in this post, but I don't like the style too much. Do you have any idea for better design, or does it seem like it might be okay after all?

Thank you all in advance!

*Table output:*

[image: Table in question.]

*Code:*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,booktabs,rotating,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Divalent and trivalent metallic cations associations in anionic clays ($^{\star}$monovalent, $^{\star\star}$tetravalent)}
\label{tab:association}
\begin{tabu}{ccccccccccc}
\cmidrule[1pt]{3-11}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Divalent cations}} \\ \cline{3-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Mg} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Mn} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Fe} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Co} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Ni} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Cu} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Zn} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Ca} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Li$^{\star}$} \\ \cline{2-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{|[1pt]c|}{\multirow{8}{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Trivalent cations}\end{sideways}}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Al} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} \\ \cline{2-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{|[1pt]c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Cr} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ \cline{2-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{|[1pt]c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Mn} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ \cline{2-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{|[1pt]c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Fe} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ \cline{2-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{|[1pt]c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Co} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ \cline{2-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{|[1pt]c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Ni} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ \cline{2-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{|[1pt]c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{La} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ \cline{2-11} 
\multicolumn{1}{|[1pt]c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Ti$^{\star\star}$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\times$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ \cline{2-11} 
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the question about the table design itself, but you can significantly simplify the table code by removing all the `\multicolumn` commands and specifying the vertical lines for the whole table. Also, I recomment *not* using `tabu` as this package is currently unmaintained. A simple `tabular` should work perfectly fine here.

Comment: I apologize, I expressed myself badly, but I wasn't asking for help simplifying the code but simply making the table more beautiful. Anyway, I wanted to use `tabu` because I can't find a way to change the thickness of the vertical lines. Anyway thank you for the suggestion, I have now used `tabular` and shortened the code a lot, but the question remains the same.

Comment: This is exactly why I started my comment with "entirely unrelated". Modifying the appearance of a table is a lot easier if one starts with a cleaner code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMNSHO, the table would look better if (a) the data columns all had the same width and (b) were spaced a bit more closely. This may be achieved by, e.g., switching from the `c` to the `w` column type type and by reducing the value of `tabcolsep`, which is the parameter that governs the amount of whitespace padding inserted on either side of each column.

That said, I would definitely also get rid of virtually all `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` wrappers. The wrappers make the code rather tedious to read, and they also make it more difficult to apply any changes or tweaks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}       % for 'w' column type
\usepackage{rotating,multirow}
\newcommand\ts{$\times$} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}        % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{1.5pt} % for a more open "look"
\centering
\caption{Divalent and trivalent metallic cations associations in
         anionic clays ($^{\star}$monovalent, $^{\star\star}$tetravalent)}
\label{tab:association}
\begin{tabular}{ *{2}{l|} *{9}{w{c}{4mm}|} }
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Divalent cations}} \\ 
\cline{3-11} 
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & Mg & Mn & Fe & Co & Ni & Cu & Zn & Ca & Li$^{\star}$ \\ 
\cline{2-11} 
\multirow{8.5}{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Trivalent cations}\end{sideways}} 
 & Al & \ts & & \ts & \ts & \ts & \ts & \ts & \ts & \ts \\ 
 \cline{2-11} 
 & Cr & & & & & \ts & \ts & \ts & & \\ 
 \cline{2-11} 
 & Mn & & \ts & & & & & & & \\ 
 \cline{2-11} 
 & Fe & \ts & & \ts & \ts & & & & & \\ 
\cline{2-11} 
 & Co & & & & \ts & \ts & & & & \\ 
 \cline{2-11} 
 & Ni & & & & & \ts & & & & \\ 
 \cline{2-11} 
 & La & & & & & \ts & & & & \\ 
 \cline{2-11} 
 & Ti$^{\star\star}$ & & & & \ts & & & & & \\ 
 \cline{2-11} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: To further "spruce up" the appearance of the table and its associated caption, one could load the `threeparttable` package and enclose the `\caption` statement and the `tabular` environment in a `threeparttable` environment. That way, the width of the caption will be set to the width of the `tabular` environment. This addition, along with the dropping the **bolding** of the row and column headers and a further decrease in the value of `\tabcolsep` (from 4pt to 3pt), would result in the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type
\usepackage{rotating,multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % for 'threeparttable' env.
\newcommand\ts{$\times$}    % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}      % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"
\caption{Divalent and trivalent metallic cation associations in 
         anionic clays ($^{\star}$mono\-valent, $^{\star\star}$tetravalent)}
\label{tab:association}
\begin{tabular}{ *{2}{l|} *{9}{w{c}{4mm}|} }
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Divalent cations} \\ 
\cline{3-11} 
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & Mg & Mn & Fe & Co & Ni & Cu & Zn & Ca & Li$^{\star}$ \\ 
\cline{2-11} 
\multirow{8.5}{*}{\begin{sideways} Trivalent cations \end{sideways}\,} 
 & Al & \ts & & \ts & \ts & \ts & \ts & \ts & \ts & \ts \\ 
 \cline{2-11} 
 & Cr & & & & & \ts & \ts & \ts & & \\ 
 \cline{2-11} 
 & Mn & & \ts & & & & & & & \\ 
 \cline{2-11} 
 & Fe & \ts & & \ts & \ts & & & & & \\ 
\cline{2-11} 
 & Co & & & & \ts & \ts & & & & \\ 
 \cline{2-11} 
 & Ni & & & & & \ts & & & & \\ 
 \cline{2-11} 
 & La & & & & & \ts & & & & \\ 
 \cline{2-11} 
 & Ti$^{\star\star}$ & & & & \ts & & & & & \\ 
 \cline{2-11} 
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!!

Answer (score 7):

So, I took the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/562389/142180) by @leandriis as a foundation.

Used booktabs, removed most of the lines. I kept both lines at the first line and column to underline that first column is similar to the first line. You might try to remove them. Also, a different symbol, hence `amssymb` include.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Mono- to tetravalent  metallic cations associations in anionic clays }
\label{tab:association}
\begin{tabular}{c|*{10}{0c}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
  & \ch{Mg^{2+}} &  \ch{Mn^{2+}}& \ch{Fe^{2+}} & \ch{Co^{2+}} & \ch{Ni^{2+}} & \ch{Cu^{2+}} & \ch{Zn^{2+}} & \ch{Ca^{2+}} & \ch{Li^{+}} \\
  \midrule
       \ch{Al^{3+}} & \checkmark     &              & \checkmark     & \checkmark     & \checkmark     & \checkmark     & \checkmark     & \checkmark     & \checkmark     \\ 
       \ch{Cr^{3+}} &              &              &              &              & \checkmark     & \checkmark     & \checkmark     &              &              \\ 
       \ch{Mn^{3+}} &              & \checkmark     &              &              &              &              &              &              &              \\ 
       \ch{Fe^{3+}} & \checkmark     &              & \checkmark     & \checkmark     &              &              &              &              &              \\ 
       \ch{Co^{3+}} &              &              &              & \checkmark     & \checkmark     &              &              &              &              \\ 
       \ch{Ni^{3+}} &              &              &              &              & \checkmark     &              &              &              &              \\ 
       \ch{La^{3+}} &              &              &              &              & \checkmark     &              &              &              &              \\ 
  \ch{Ti^{4+}} &              &              &              & \checkmark     &              &              &              &              &              \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

Here is another suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,rotating,multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{bbding}
\newcommand\xs{\cellcolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}\XSolid}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\centering
\caption{Divalent and trivalent metallic cations associations
         in anionic clays ($^{\star}$monovalent, $^{\star\star}$tetravalent)}
\label{tab:association}
\begin{tabular}{ *{2}{ >{\bfseries}l}!{\vrule width 1.2pt}w{c}{5mm} *{8}{|w{c}{5mm}}!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
\multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Divalent cations}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \mc{Mg} & \mc{Mn} & \mc{Fe} & \mc{Co} & \mc{Ni} & \mc{Cu} & \mc{Zn} & \mc{Ca} & \mc{Li$^{\star}$} \\[1ex]
\cmidrule[1.2pt](l{-1.2pt}){3-11}
\multirow{8.5}{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Trivalent cations}\end{sideways}\enspace}
 & Al & \xs & & \xs & \xs & \xs & \xs & \xs & \xs & \xs \\
\cmidrule[0.4pt](l{-1.2pt}){3-11}
 & Cr & & & & & \xs & \xs & \xs & & \\
\cmidrule[0.4pt](l{-1.2pt}){3-11}
 & Mn & & \xs & & & & & & & \\
\cmidrule[0.4pt](l{-1.2pt}){3-11}
 & Fe & \xs & & \xs & \xs & & & & & \\
\cmidrule[0.4pt](l{-1.2pt}){3-11}
 & Co & & & & \xs & \xs & & & & \\
\cmidrule[0.4pt](l{-1.2pt}){3-11}
 & Ni & & & & & \xs & & & & \\
\cmidrule[0.4pt](l{-1.2pt}){3-11}
 & La & & & & & \xs & & & & \\
\cmidrule[0.4pt](l{-1.2pt}){3-11}
 & Ti$^{\star\star}$ & & & & \xs & & & & & \\[-1.2pt]
\cmidrule[1.2pt](l{-1.2pt}){3-11}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simplified version of your code in which I replaced `tabu` with `tabular` and removed all redundant `\multicolumn` commands. I have also added a second slightly different version, in which I added the charge of the ions using `chemmformula` (loaded by `chemmacros`) and added some white space above and below the text in each cell using the `cellspace` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{0.5\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Divalent and trivalent metallic cations associations in anionic clays ($^{\star}$monovalent, $^{\star\star}$tetravalent)}
\label{tab:association}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{}  
     & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Divalent cations}} \\ \cline{3-11} 
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} 
                          &   Mg     &   Mn     & Fe       & Co       & Ni       & Cu       & Zn       & Ca       & Li$^{\star}$ \\ \cline{2-11} 
\multirow{8}{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Trivalent cations}\end{sideways}} 
      & Al                & $\times$ &          & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$      \\ \cline{2-11} 
      & Cr                &          &          &          &          & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ &          &               \\ \cline{2-11} 
      & Mn                &          & $\times$ &          &          &          &          &          &          &               \\ \cline{2-11} 
      & Fe                & $\times$ &          & $\times$ & $\times$ &          &          &          &          &               \\ \cline{2-11} 
      & Co                &          &          &          & $\times$ & $\times$ &          &          &          &               \\ \cline{2-11} 
      & Ni                &          &          &          &          & $\times$ &          &          &          &               \\ \cline{2-11} 
      & La                &          &          &          &          & $\times$ &          &          &          &               \\ \cline{2-11} 
      & Ti$^{\star\star}$ &          &          &          & $\times$ &          &          &          &          &               \\ \cline{2-11} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Mono- to tetravalent  metallic cations associations in anionic clays }
\label{tab:association}
\begin{tabular}{|*{11}{0c|}}
\cline{2-10}
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} 
                    & \ch{Mg^{2+}} &  \ch{Mn^{2+}}& \ch{Fe^{2+}} & \ch{Co^{2+}} & \ch{Ni^{2+}} & \ch{Cu^{2+}} & \ch{Zn^{2+}} & \ch{Ca^{2+}} & \ch{Li^{+}} \\ \hline   
       \ch{Al^{3+}} & $\times$     &              & $\times$     & $\times$     & $\times$     & $\times$     & $\times$     & $\times$     & $\times$     \\ \hline 
       \ch{Cr^{3+}} &              &              &              &              & $\times$     & $\times$     & $\times$     &              &              \\ \hline
       \ch{Mn^{3+}} &              & $\times$     &              &              &              &              &              &              &              \\ \hline 
       \ch{Fe^{3+}} & $\times$     &              & $\times$     & $\times$     &              &              &              &              &              \\ \hline 
       \ch{Co^{3+}} &              &              &              & $\times$     & $\times$     &              &              &              &              \\ \hline 
       \ch{Ni^{3+}} &              &              &              &              & $\times$     &              &              &              &              \\ \hline 
       \ch{La^{3+}} &              &              &              &              & $\times$     &              &              &              &              \\ \hline 
       \ch{Ti^{4+}} &              &              &              & $\times$     &              &              &              &              &              \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second table looks great! Thank you @leandriis!
Unfortunately, those `\multicolumn` in my code came up because I subconsciously used an online table generator.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily draw that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is constructed upon `{array}` (of `array`).

For the rules, you only have to use the keys `hvlines` and `corners` and all the required rules are drawn (provided you have used the keys `first-row` and `first-col` to specify that there are a row 'before' the array and a column on the left 'outside' the array).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand\ts{$\times$}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1.5pt}
\centering
\caption{Divalent and trivalent metallic cations associations 
         in anionic clays ($^{\star}$monovalent, $^{\star\star}$tetravalent)}
\label{tab:association}
\begin{NiceTabular}{l*{9}{w{c}{4mm}}}[first-row,first-col,hvlines,corners=NW]
&  & 
\multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Divalent cations}} \\ 
& & Mg & Mn & Fe & Co & Ni & Cu & Zn & Ca & Li$^{\star}$ \\ 
\Block{8-1}{\rotate \textbf{Trivalent cations}}\hspace*{2mm}%
 & Al & \ts & & \ts & \ts & \ts & \ts & \ts & \ts & \ts \\ 
 & Cr & & & & & \ts & \ts & \ts & & \\ 
 & Mn & & \ts & & & & & & & \\ 
 & Fe & \ts & & \ts & \ts & & & & & \\ 
 & Co & & & & \ts & \ts & & & & \\ 
 & Ni & & & & & \ts & & & & \\ 
 & La & & & & & \ts & & & & \\ 
 & Ti$^{\star\star}$ & & & & \ts & & & & & \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 4):

Adding minute details to research work or theses is distracting and might even be offensive: an expert in the field *knows* about cations that are divalent or trivalent or both (and the reviewer of a thesis will look whether *you* know about them). Therefore I'd omit the long labels; you can reinsert them, if you so prefer.

Some detail can be added to the caption itself, just for completeness; the optional argument to `\caption` is just for that: you can include information in the actual caption without it being in the list of tables.

Adding cages around entries is likewise distracting. Some additional space between rows makes it easy to follow them. I set all cells to a fixed width of 1.5em and used `\Y` in the input to avoid cluttering the code, so you can visually check the input very easily.

All those `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` are evil! The cells were already declared as `c|`, so why overriding them just to use the same alignment?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption
  [Divalent and trivalent metallic cations associations in anionic clays]
  {Divalent and trivalent metallic cations associations in anionic clays; 
   * is monovalent, ** is tetravalent, rows list trivalent
   cations, columns list divalent cations}
\label{tab:association}

% local command for simplifying input and reading
\newcommand{\Y}{$\times$}

\begin{tabular}{@{} w{l}{1.5em} *{9}{w{c}{1.5em}} @{}}
\toprule
     & Mg & Mn & Fe & Co & Ni & Cu & Zn & Ca & Li* \\
\midrule
Al   & \Y &    & \Y & \Y & \Y & \Y & \Y & \Y & \Y \\
\addlinespace
Cr   &    &    &    &    & \Y & \Y & \Y &    &    \\
\addlinespace
Mn   &    & \Y &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\
\addlinespace
Fe   & \Y &    & \Y & \Y &    &    &    &    &    \\
\addlinespace
Co   &    &    &    & \Y & \Y &    &    &    &    \\
\addlinespace
Ni   &    &    &    &    & \Y &    &    &    &    \\
\addlinespace
La   &    &    &    &    & \Y &    &    &    &    \\
\addlinespace
Ti** &    &    &    & \Y &    &    &    &    &    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The version with the labels. Since some amount of guessing is needed also with `\multirow`, I chose to set the rotated label outside of the table, anchoring it to the bottom in order to make for an easier guess.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,caption,rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption
  [Divalent and trivalent metallic cations associations in anionic clays]
  {Divalent and trivalent metallic cations associations in anionic clays; 
   * is monovalent, ** is tetravalent, rows list trivalent
   cations, columns list divalent cations}
\label{tab:association}

% local command for simplifying input and reading
\newcommand{\Y}{$\times$}

\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[11.5\normalbaselineskip]{Trivalent cations}}\quad
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{} w{l}{1.5em} *{9}{w{c}{1.5em}} @{}}
\toprule
     & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Divalent cations} \\
     & Mg & Mn & Fe & Co & Ni & Cu & Zn & Ca & Li* \\
\midrule
Al   & \Y &    & \Y & \Y & \Y & \Y & \Y & \Y & \Y \\
\addlinespace
Cr   &    &    &    &    & \Y & \Y & \Y &    &    \\
\addlinespace
Mn   &    & \Y &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\
\addlinespace
Fe   & \Y &    & \Y & \Y &    &    &    &    &    \\
\addlinespace
Co   &    &    &    & \Y & \Y &    &    &    &    \\
\addlinespace
Ni   &    &    &    &    & \Y &    &    &    &    \\
\addlinespace
La   &    &    &    &    & \Y &    &    &    &    \\
\addlinespace
Ti** &    &    &    & \Y &    &    &    &    &    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]